# How to clear HTML form that handles file download and does not navigate away

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post, reset

I have a form that takes some input and sends a POST request back to a Spring Boot instance, which triggers a file download through content disposition header.

The browser handles the download perfectly but it does not navigate away from the page, which is the normal behavior.

Now, the inputs contain sensitive information that must not remain in the form.

I can only intercept the form's onsubmit function but I can not use ajax to make the requests because the server returns multiple pages depending the state of the data (i.e bad input, wrong information, etc)

Clearing the fields before submission erases the form and all data gets lost.

Is there a way to clear the fields before or after the form has been submitted?

Comment: Try '    $("form").trigger("reset");'

Comment: @Dhara Where does that code go? Inside onsubmit it still resets the form. Even after calling form.submit

Comment: @TheRealChx101 Dhara's suggestion is just a jQuery way to clear a form. I don't have a robust solution to this, setting a timeout, and clearing the form with a small delay feels a bit hackish.